# access users information by only having their UID

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to access users information by only having their uid. I am not sure how to go about this and was wondering if anyone had any clues. In the Image below, this user has a post, but inside of this post is just information about the post, not about the user. I was thinking that since I had saved this post information under the users uid, I could then go in and access that users information, such as name and profile image to have displayed on top of the post. or Should I save the users name and profile image as well when I update the post?

[image]

Comment: A user using a client-side SDK for Firebase Authentication can only look up their own user information. So if you want some of that information to be readable to other users, you'll have to store that in the database too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want per-user information to be available to others, you will have to store it somewhere in your database.  You can store it in node specific to that user, using their UID, or you can store it along with the data that references it.  It's completely up to you, but you have to store it somewhere.

Comment: The users information is stored under my users block in firebase. so what youre saying is if I would like to access this users name, I would have to store it when the user stores a post?

Comment: What do you mean by "users block"?  If you're referring to another location in the database, then you can just query that location.  But if you don't want to do that, you can store it along with the other data.  As I said in my answer, it's entirely up to you.